# How to get a success callback of session expire (inactivity) in Apache Unomi 2.0

Tags: java, maven, jahia, cdp, apache-unomi

I am using Apache Unomi 2.0. Apache Unomi is maintaining a sessionId, which represents a period of time during which a visitor or profile has been active, and all the events are bound to one sessionId, the running sessionId of that particular profile.

My question is this:

Q1. How can we terminate this running session from the front end when a user clicks on the logout button?

Q2. If user don't  click on logout button then how to get the auto-success callback from the unomi-server that this sessionId is inactive from their last event.(to the scheduled session timeout) So that we can run the session abandoned logic.

Q3. How to update this session-time out value.

Thanks